# How is CIC interpolation gain calculated?

Tags: digital-filters

For a programmable [CIC interpolation IP core](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=1163535) configured as follows:

- Input bits : 17
- Output bits : 49 (Full precision output)
- Stages, N : 5
- Diff Delay, M : 1

According to E. B. Hogenauer in [An economical class of digital filters for decimation and interpolation](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=1163535), Equation 22,
$G_j=\begin{cases}2^j, & \text{$j$ = 1, 2, ..., N} \\\frac{2^{2N-j}(RM)^{j-N}}{R} & \text{$j$ = N+1, 2, ..., 2N}\end{cases}$ (eq 1)

For the output stage case when j = 2N, the equation above simplifies to:
$G_j=\frac{(RM)^N}{R}$ (eq 2)

The issue is that the gain does not match the Equation 2b.

Xilinx Vivado Simulation of R = 4
[image: R=4 Simulation]

As it turns out Dan Boschen is right. The input is a square wave and
not DC as I had alluded. I was trying to eliminate a CFIR for a square wave. Looks like I'll need to look at the CIC roll off at the frequency of the square wave.
[image: CIC gain with DC input]

Comment: By input of 32767 you mean your signal is DC?

Comment: I see from the Xilinx document that the gain depends of the interpolation rate. Are you sure to correctly implemement the AXI handshaking while feeding input samples?

Comment: Input is actually a square [32767, -32768] but I am interested in DC gain keeping the CFIR out of the discussion. As for feeding the core, I am feeding samples in correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the OP may be testing with a tone rather than DC which would result in reduced gain given the $Sinc^N$ roll-off over frequency.

Regardless, a single stage CIC Filter for interpolation by rate $I$ is mathematically equivalent to zero-insert of $I-1$ zeros followed by a "moving average" filter over $I$ samples (FIR filter with unity gain coefficients as shown in the graphic below as simply the sum of $I$ samples without dividing by $I$, as would be done in a true moving average). Each additional stage is mathematically equivalent to an additional moving average filter over $I$ samples. The DC gain of $N$ moving average filters in cascade is $I^N$, and the gain of the zero insert is $1/N$, thus resulting in a net gain  of $I^{(N-1)}$. Therefore a 5 stage CIC should have a DC gain of $I^4$.

[image: CIC]